# The Windows Azure toolkit for Windows Phone 7 Project template is throwing StorageClientException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, azure

I am following the video on

http://watoolkitwp7.codeplex.com/

to set up Azure toolkit for WP7.  I have installed everything. 
I have created a new "windows Phone 7 cloud application" project. 
When I try to run it, it keeps throwing StorageClientException.

I even try to put the code where this occurs in a try catch block, but this results
in Azure not starting properly.

Here is a picture of the error: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/835/azureerror.png/

Help will be appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav produced a very handy list of things which aren't available in development storage :
http://www.cerebrata.com/Blog/post/Development-Storage-Vs-Azure-Storage.aspx

Sadly this includes $root - you'll have to use a "real" storage account if you want to use $root